# magento how to get attributes associated with a single product using database query

Tags: php, database, magento, magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

We are trying to get all attributes associated with each product using a database.

We have been used following query but I think the table we are using is not the right one.

```
$sql = "SELECT attribute_id FROM catalog_product_index_eav WHERE entity_id=".$entityprodid;
```

This table is not the exact table which will get all attributes attached to a single product id.

Any suggestions how do we get attributes of a single product in Magento using database ??

Comment: EAV is central to Magento's design. While I haven't worked with it in a long time (by choice), I would suggest reviewing their [technical documentation](https://magento.com/resources/technical), as there should be a canonical way to do this rather than going directly to the database. Also, they have [their own StackExchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/), which might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses flat tables to centralize the attributes of products, so to query all the attributes by the ID, you can use the table catalog_product_flat, remembering that for this table to be updated, it is necessary to reindex the data.

Comment: if my product id = 7051 for example, so i want what multiselect attributes are there with this product id?? The answer suggested by you will help us in this or is there any other table which stores this data?? Is there any sql query to find this data by joining 2 table.

Comment: That's right, all products included in the Magento catalog are stored in the catalog_product_flat table after reindexing. Remembering that the site needs to be configured to use flat tables, System> Configuration> Catalog> Frontend> "Use Flat Product Catalog"